# JList: Horizontal_WRAP fitted?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Hey,.. i wanna show pictures with names onit in a jList, i know it get's also in a JPanel but i'm now using a jList, doesn't matter..

**My question is** why does the jlist don't fit the images only in 2 horizontal 'cells' and then go one row down?

sry my english is bad and i don't know how to describe it better, but look on the picture, why does the jlist dont set the e.g. 3rd picture right next to the 2nd?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP` works correctly in the [`ListDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ListDialogRunnerProject/src/components/ListDialog.java) JWS [demo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/ListDialogRunner.jnlp), as described in [*Initializing a List*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#init). I suspect a layout problem, but you might compare your code to the examples found there.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HORIZONTAL_WRAP you can adjust the number of columns with setVisibleRowCount. If you want them automatically fitted to the width of the list, use 0 or something negative.